# jtidy fails to parse html - options

Tags: html, parsing, html-parsing, jtidy

So I was trying to evaluate a couple of the HTML parsers and gave JTidy a try. Trying to parse this URL:

http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/doc/org/htmlcleaner/TagNode.html

Gives these errors:

> line 1 column 56,258 - Error:  missing '>' for end of tag
>
> line 1 column 56,258 - Error:  is not recognized!

It says line one as it reads it in as one line, but this is the line that JTidy pukes/fails on:

```
      <li>//div[last() >= 4]//./div[position() = last()])[position() > 22]//li[2]//a</li>
```

My code is pretty simple:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.tidy.Tidy;

Document document = tidy.parseDOM(new ByteArrayInputStream(this.getHtml().getBytes()), null);
NodeList anchorTags = document.getElementsByTagName("A");
```

Is this just a bug in JTidy or am I doing something wrong? I've evaluated about 6 others so far and none of them have had a problem on this page.

Comment: No idea as to the problem with `JTidy`. I use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) for my HTML parsing. It's excellent.

Comment: JSoup is one of the packages I have done some sample evaluations with and really like it, I just want to go through most to give a detailed proposal to my tech review group. I'd at least like to say I had vetted JTidy and it has too many bugs to be used out of the box for even our simple needs at this point.

Comment: I'd go with the "JTidy has too many bugs to be used out of the box" evaluation. :)